# Isabelle proving with translation issue

Tags: isabelle

I had defined a few translations like this:

```
consts
  "time" :: "i"
  "sig" :: "i ⇒ i"
  "BaseChTy" :: "i"

syntax
  "time" :: "i"
  "sig" :: "i ⇒ i"
translations
  "time" ⇌ "CONST int"
  "sig(A)" ⇌ "CONST int → A"
```

Then, I want to prove a theorem like this:

```
theorem sig_mono: "⟦ A ⊆ B ⟧ ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B)"
```

It should be a very simple theorem, and should be proved with theorem *Pi_mono* in a single step:

```
thm Pi_mono
?B ⊆ ?C ⟹ ?A → ?B ⊆ ?A → ?C
```

So I did it like this:

```
theorem sig_mono: "⟦ A ⊆ B ⟧ ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B)"

apply(drule Pi_mono[of _ _ "time"])
(*Output:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. sig(A) ⊆ sig(B) ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B)
*)

apply(simp)
(*Output:
Failed ...
*)
```

Since the premise has become the same as the goal, it should be proved immediately, but it didn't. May I know have I done anything wrong in the translation definition?
I tried to change the theorem to:

```
theorem sig_mono: "⟦ A ⊆ B ⟧ ⟹ (time → A) ⊆ (time → B)"
(*Output:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. A ⊆ B ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B)
*)

apply(drule Pi_mono[of _ _ "time"])
(*Output:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. sig(A) ⊆ sig(B) ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B)
*)

apply(simp)
(*Output:
Success ...
*)
```

Then it works immediately, but shouldn't the translation will make them to be the same thing?

Update:
Thanks for Mathias Fleury reply, I tried to do a simplify trace, and it shows something like this:

```
theorem sig_mono: "⟦ A ⊆ B ⟧ ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B)"
using [[show_sorts]] apply(drule Pi_mono[of _ _ "time"])
using [[simp_trace]] apply(simp)
oops

(*
Output:
[1]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
sig(A::i) ⊆ sig(B::i) ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B) 
[1]Adding rewrite rule "??.unknown":
sig(A::i) ⊆ sig(B::i) ≡ True 
*)
```

while the *time -> A* version shows:

```
theorem sig_mono: "⟦ A ⊆ B ⟧ ⟹ time → A ⊆ time → B"
using [[show_sorts]] apply(drule Pi_mono[of _ _ "time"])
using [[simp_trace]] apply(simp)
oops

(*
Output:
[1]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
sig(A::i) ⊆ sig(B::i) ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B) 
[1]Adding rewrite rule "??.unknown":
sig(A::i) ⊆ sig(B::i) ≡ True 
[1]Applying instance of rewrite rule "??.unknown":
sig(A::i) ⊆ sig(B::i) ≡ True 
[1]Rewriting:
sig(A::i) ⊆ sig(B::i) ≡ True
*)
```

Why can this time version can apply the instance of rewrite rule to continue to the proof, but the original one does not?

Comment: It would be easier if your example would type or if you could give the imports you are using… What does the arrow in sig mean?

Comment: Some suggestions: i) check with supply [[show_types]] that the types are really the same; ii) check with `supply [[unify_trace_failure]] apply assumption` why no unification happens; iii) check with supply [[show_sorts]] that the sorts are really the same

Comment: The imports are: `imports Nlist IntExt Hilbert ZF.Univ`, where Nlist IntExt Hilbert are written on my own, but all of them does not have any definition related to `time` or `time -> A`, they only contains theorem about `int`, the arrow means that it is a function from time (in here it is int) to set A. I would have a look on the supply command, thank you very much.

Comment: The problem is that the translation does not work for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the imports you mentioned in you comment (thanks), I could reproduce the problem. The issue is the translation, you need to do something like

```
syntax
  "sig" :: "i ⇒ i" (‹sig(_)›)
translations
  "sig(A)" == "CONST int → A"

theorem sig_mono: "⟦ A ⊆ B ⟧ ⟹ sig(A) ⊆ sig(B)"
  apply(rule Pi_mono)
  apply assumption
  done
```

Just to expand on my comment and explain how I found that the problem is the translation. I looked at the unification failure:

```
theorem ⟦ A ⊆ B ⟧ ⟹ time → A ⊆ time → B
  supply[[unify_trace_failure]]
   apply (rule PI_mono)
```

The error message tells that `sig` and `Pi` are not unifiable. This is already strange. To be certain that the problem comes from the translation, I looked at the underlying term:

```
ML ‹@{print}@{term ‹sig(A)›}›
```

It shows the underlying term and we can see that the translation is not working and I looked at other translations in the library to fix issue.

Comment: I see, so I must put the bracket thing after the syntax declaration. How do you see the translation is not working from the ML code? And do you meet an ambiguous warning in the theorem?

Comment: The ML shows you the term after unfolding of the translation if there is any. For the ambiguous, one solution is to replace the syntax by `abbreviation sig where ‹sig(A) == CONST int → A› `

Comment: `syntax "sig" :: "i ⇒ i" ("sig(_)" [70] 70)` to keep the translation.

Comment: Thank you very much. To your understanding, do you think there is difference if I replace the int with time? For example, `abbreviation sig where ‹sig(A) == CONST time → A›` or `"sig(A)" == "CONST time → A"`.

Comment: The abbreviation allows you to write `sig A` instead of `sig(A)`. Otherwise, for `int` or `times`, there should be no difference (I just replaced it while debugging and forgot to readd it)